# mongodb: get element of nested array by condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Need to get element of nested array by condition. Origin collection:

```
[
  {
    code: 134,
    bindings: [
      {
        devId: "71156ce8-ac2b-4282-9f5a-10133441057c",
        userIds: ["9d300b89-29c0-45a8-a4d3-019cfc8f1c7b"]
      },
      {
        devId: "ca33efa1-ec27-4ee1-8117-8b8ab29c1790",
        userIds: ["73e5af2f-fe01-41a3-bebd-6bab895cab58"]
      },
      {
        devId: "a03f5fbd-f279-4182-bfb6-33aba9de5751",
        userIds: ["dc0c5e59-ef1a-44b9-843b-a4ea73bbed2e"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I try use aggregation function :

```
db.trigger.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: "134" } },
  { $unwind: "$bindings" },
  { $match: { "bindings.devId": "ca33efa1-ec27-4ee1-8117-8b8ab29c1790" } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, dateset: 1 } },
  { $out: "bindings" }
]);
```

but it did not give the desired result. Сan someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sample document has `code` set to `134` while in your query you're trying to match _id which is a string. Could you show us the desired result ?

Comment: desired result :
{
        devId: "71156ce8-ac2b-4282-9f5a-10133441057c",
        userIds: ["9d300b89-29c0-45a8-a4d3-019cfc8f1c7b"]
      }
element of array with specific devId

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation, [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) promotes nested document into root level:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { code: 134 }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$bindings"
    },
    {
        $match: { "bindings.devId": "71156ce8-ac2b-4282-9f5a-10133441057c" }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$bindings" }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y99KO1MaQ7V)

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot!